# Custom editortemplate when property has some attribute on it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is what the implementation would look like

```
public class Product
{
    public integer id {get;set;}
    [MultiLangual]
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

In the database, name would contain something like:

```
{en:Pataoto, nl: Aardappel, de: Patat, fr: pommes de terre}
```

This would contain all the translated fields, that a client has given to his own product.
(in this case: a patato).

In the frontend, this would appear as multiple html elements, which i (somehow) detect which language it is, on submitting the form.

My question is, how would i do this? I'm always stuck on creating the attribute and don't know where to continue...

In my attribute, i shouldn't do a lot, just something like this (i think):

```
public class MultiLangualAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MultiLangualAttribute() : base()
    { 
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

But how would i detect everything in my views and create a custom layout for it (this should work with  and .
It would only contain text.

Any ideas or a better implementation of above, would be VERY usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the better (arguably) implementation is standard way of application localization.
You define your resources and strings under `App_GlobalResources` folder you will have to create.
For example you will create file `Fruits.resx` with all your fruits you want to translate in your system language.
Afterwards you will create `Fruits.de.resx`, `Fruits.es.resx` etc, with all the languages you want to have in your website.
It is also possible to update the resources at runtime.
Its too much to describe all the approach in this answer, I would rather provide a link or two with detailed tutorial on MVC application localization:

- This is classic ASP.NET MVC localization explanation:
  [Globalization And Localization With Razor Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/183/Globalization-And-Localization-With-Razor-Web-Pages)
- Another explanation of the same thing, little more detailed is here: 
  [ASP.NET MVC Localization: Generate resource files and localized views using custom templates](http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/asp-net-mvc-localization-generate-resource-files-and-localized-views-using-custom-templates/)
  This should be enough for you to localize your app the standard way.
- This is a little more advanced approach, when they use language as part of the URL you accessing. 
  `es.yourdomain.com` will be in Spanish, `fr.yourdomain.com` will be in French: 
  [Localization in ASP.NET MVC – 3 Days Investigation, 1 Day Job](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx)
- With regards to your approach (storing different languages in the database) here's link to microsoft approach for this. Its much more involved and complex, and I am not sure if benefitting you by its complexity, since you end up using database to fetch every single string in your app. Not the most efficient, but possible approach as well:
  [Extending the ASP.NET Resource-Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx)

Hope this all will be of helps to you & good luck